# How does poweroff (or halt, reboot etc) work when symlinked to systemctl?

Tags: debian, systemd

I am running Debian Stretch. When I do `file /sbin/reboot` (or any related command) it says it is symlinked to `/bin/systemctl` without any kind of parameters as far as I know.

**How does `systemctl` know I want to reboot? Does it check `argv[0]` and does a switch/case in the code?**

It also works when I run it elsewhere (`ln --symbolic /bin/systemctl ~/bin/reboot` for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it check `argv[0]` and does a switch/case in the code?

Study the code and find for yourself. But I'm sure the general answer is: yes, something like that.

---

This is a known trick. Take BusyBox as an example. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BusyBox#Single_binary):

> Typical computer programs have a separate binary (executable) file for each application. BusyBox is a single binary, which is a conglomerate of many applications, each of which can be accessed by calling the single BusyBox binary with various names (supported by having a symbolic link or hard link for each different name) in a specific manner with appropriate arguments.

Bash is yet another example. From [`man bash`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> If `bash` is invoked with the name `sh`, it tries to mimic the startup behavior of historical versions of `sh` as closely as possible, while conforming to the POSIX standard as well.

Check `/bin/sh` in your Debian Stretch. It's a symlink to (probably)... `dash`. [This site](https://wiki.debian.org/Shell) explains:

> Up to Debian Lenny, the default `/bin/sh` shell was `bash`. Starting with Debian Squeeze, the default shell will be `dash`.